# Solr query with slop

Tags: solr, solrj

I want to construct a query at **Solr** 4.6.1.

I've indexed a lot of a data:
*id*
*name*
*description*
*etc*

And I've used a **copyField** (with a slop of 100) in my field **"all"**, so I have:

```
all: id [100 spaces] name [100 spaces]...etc
```

I want to make a query similar to this:

```
`all: play* AND all: "Bars Warehouse"`
```

but I want, that search only at one field,

I mind, find  play* and "Bars Warehouse" at name or find  play* and "Bars Warehouse" at description.

Can I do this? I know that, if I execute this query 
`"play Bars Warehouse"~98` it will make something similar to what i want, but I will miss the wildcard.

Could you help me with that?

Comment: so, you want a query with slop, with wildcard and on one particular field, right?

Comment: exactly, that's what i want but i cannot figure out how to do it (I suppose it can be done)

Comment: okay, it's clear to me how to do, what you want, but the only unclear stuff to me - it's how the copyField is related here, is it important for question or I missing something?

Comment: also, please share your schema.xml